# selinux, git and var/www

Tags: apache-2.2, git, selinux

Here's my situation:
what i want to do is to "git clone" a project under /var/www. But since i'm logged into my server as idcuser selinux (I suppose :D) doesn't permit me to do it.

How can I "give" permission to my user to write under /var/www and, in the same time, let apache continue to read/write the files "cloned".

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What does this have to do with SELinux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use extended acl for you file system. First chown to www-data/httpd for your entire folder. After use setfacl to add extended acl to the same folder:

setfacl -m u:your_user:rwx -R folder

I presume you are using ext3/4 and you already have all compiled in your kernel (older versions of kernel 2.6 didn't had acl support enabled).

If you get: 
setfacl: folder: Operation not supported

then you should remount the partition with acl support:

mount -oremount,defaults,acl /parition

and don't forget to add it to fstab for later use.

Remember, for any new file added you should do the same steps:
1. chown www-data
2. setfacl